# Integrating plugins from github to html

Tags: javascript, github, twitter-bootstrap-3

Okay, I know this is a beginner question and may sound dumb because I hardly know anything about coding. So, forgive my ignorance.

I'm building this website with Bootstrap 3 framework and found quite a lot of cool plugins on github (e.g https://github.com/ixisio/bootstrap-touch-carousel). I know nothing about it, so I tried to research on what github is.

A lot of introductions out there only cover the 'Why github is useful' and 'Simple beginner's command line on github'. But what about the next step? A lot of documentation and Quickstart document on these plugins are very brief and seems to assume that you already know the basics.

It's quite intimidating to have to write cmd lines, and then bombarded with new terms like 'bower', 'grunt', 'npm' or 'json'. I'm just completely lost at what steps do I have to take to take those plugins and apply them to my html.

What I humbly ask from you guys is, please explain the steps from installing github up to having the plugins functions applied to my html site. And please explain it as if I'm 5 :)

I even have question like 'Why the heck would you go through the trouble of installing git shell and write those command lines when you can just hit that cute Download as Zip button' But then when I did that, of course none of it has worked for me so far... so I suspect there's a large step I was missing.

Comment: you should start learning what is distributed version control `git` or `mercurial`. Lets oversimplify `github` as a hub for git projects open source and otherwise. You should start with git

Answer (score 0):

Best suggestion is look at the source code on the demo page. Note the css and scripts that are specific to that plugin.

Then download the source from github and add appropriate css and scripts based on paths you download them too.

Then follow other docs to initialize the plugin. 
When you are ready to try your plugin make sure to check browser console for any errors that are thrown.

If you see things like `$.myPlugin is not a function` type error then your path to the plugin file is probably not right.